# How do you use VLOOKUP with vertically merged columns (merging that span rows)?

Tags: google-search

Let's say I have a table like this, where `B` is vertically merged for `A=1` and `A=2`

```
A | B
------
1   f
2   o
3   
4   b
5   a
6   r
```

How can I look up the value of `B`, for `A=3`? The way I see it, `A=2` and `A=3` *share* a `B`, but the way [Google Sheets's `VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) seems to think of it, `A=3` has no matching `B`. This seems like a bad design because the cell is only *visually* `MERGING` across the row but *functionally* you're losing data. Is there a workaround for this?

This returns nothing,

```
=VLOOKUP(3, A1:B6, 2)
```

While this returns `o`

```
=VLOOKUP(2, A1:B6, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values in the lookup column are numerical and in ascending order:

`=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(3,A:A/(B:B<>""),B:B))`

Comment: Could you explain that a bit?